# Publish all contents of a Laravel package

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I installed a Laravel package via composer and require some of the non-published controllers of it to be published (to be safely modified by me and still being able to run `composer install` without overwriting custom code). However, I wouldn't find any appropriate answers on Google.

Basically, `php artisan vendor:publish` publishes some of the files of the package ***but not all***. Is there a way to modify what files `vendor:publish` publishes? As stated, I'll need some controllers of the vendor folder to be published.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#publishing-file-groups

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in the package's provider class and tags for what you want to publish

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Namespace\ProviderClass" --tag="config|lang"
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/packages#publishing-file-groups

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
php artisan vendor:publish --all
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I think this will publish all the packages rather than a specific one.